# How to get name of file in request.POST?

Tags: python, django

In my request.FILES variables:

```
FILES
Variable    Value
script  <InMemoryUploadedFile: landing.jpg (image/jpeg)>
```

How would I pull the filename here in order to get "landing.jpg" ?

Comment: are you trying to access the name in a view or put the name into the POST data from the web page?

Comment: In the view (to save it to the model).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Via [`request.FILES[u'script'].name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name).